# error - Type.registerNamespace(“SP”) is undefined

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, sharepoint-email

I have a problem in my test environment.
When trying to call send a mail function I created,
I'm getting the error:
Type.registerNamespace(“SP”) is undefined.

In my Dev environment, everything works fine. the problem only occurs on a new test server we created.

I've been checking the problem online and found that I need to add a reference to MicrosoftAjax.js.

Can anyone help with his issue?

Thank You

Comment: Should you post your current code ?

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this issue , you need to use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method that used to delay a function call unless a particular script (SP) is loaded.

To use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` do the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function yourfunction(){

                             }
     ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourfunction,"SP.js");
</script>
```

If you are working with a JSOM inside app page , you should reference `MicrosoftAjax.js` as a prerequisite to work with JSOM as the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Type your code here.
</script>
```

Or as the following

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script>


   $(document).ready(function(){
        var scriptbase = "http://Qassas/" + "/_layouts/15/";
    //Do not change the order, scripts should load by order.  
     $.getScript(scriptbase + "init.js",
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
                   function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", execOperation);
              });
          });
           });
// **add your code**
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I added this line: <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="MicrosoftAjax.js" OnDemand="true"  LoadAfterUI="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" /> and also on the aspx page, but i'm still getting this error.   The problem is that I'm getting the error only on specific server. do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try to add it like this "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script>" as I mentioned above , also please update your question with your current code